# How to import recurring payment data from Stripe and GoCardless so that it updates memberships?

Tags: import, stripe, gocardless

I'm setting up a new CiviCRM site and importing a few thousand contacts and membership records from a bespoke legacy database. Many of the payments for the memberships are handled by Stripe or GoCardless, but there was never any automation in place so all of the membership updates were done manually. With CiviCRM I can get new memberships to update automatically using webhoook data from Stripe and GoCardless, but what about the memberships that have already been created?

I've found [this script](https://github.com/artfulrobot/uk.artfulrobot.civicrm.gocardless/blob/master/cli/import-from-gc.php) from Rich Lott which looks like it might do what I need (if I can work out how to use it), for GoCardless. How have other people made this stuff work? Is there anything out there that could help me with Stripe? Certainly I won't be the first to need a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

there's https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe which has tools for importing from Stripe.

Good luck!

Comment: OK, thanks. I wasn't aware that the Stripe extension could import over and above current transactions - I'll look into that.

Comment: The docs suggest that the import functionality that I'm after might be a future roadmap feature? https://docs.civicrm.org/stripe/en/latest/roadmap/ ?